# How to check if individual nodes in a storm cluster are setup correctly?

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-storm

I have setup a storm cluster by following the steps on a guide. One way to test the topology is to deploy my code and see if that works, but other than that is there any tool/other way to check if the setup is done properly or not and are all the nodes able to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if all nodes are available in Storm UI (http://storm_ui_ip:8080).
In "Supervisor summary" you must see the list of all nodes with their IP addresses.

Comment: It can say each supervisor is connected to Zookeeper (and Nimbus) successfully, but it doesn't ensure each worker can connect others.